# Two same components re-renders with the first one's props' values (TypeScript, React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a certain component called `UploadOnePhoto` and it takes a property named `type` of kind `PhotoType` (enum).

*Enum defintion:*

```
export enum PhotoType {
  LOGO = "logo",
  PROFILE = "profile",
}
```

I render those two components in a Stack like this:

```
<Stack direction="row" spacing="3.3rem">
    <UploadOnePhoto type={PhotoType.PROFILE} onSubmit={onAddPhoto} />
    <Divider orientation="vertical" />
    <UploadOnePhoto type={PhotoType.LOGO} onSubmit={onAddPhoto} />
</Stack>
```

*UploadOnePhoto component:*

```
interface UploadOnePhotoProps {
  onSubmit?: (selectedFile: FileObj | null, type: PhotoType) => void;
  type: PhotoType;
}

export function UploadOnePhoto(props: UploadOnePhotoProps) {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<FileObj | null>(null);
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [openPreviewImg, setOpenPreviewImg] = useState(false);

  const [filePreview, setFilePreview] = useState<string>("");
  const onChange = (cropper: CropperRef) => {
    console.log("change:" + currentType);

    console.log(cropper.getCoordinates(), cropper.getCanvas());
  };
  const currentType = useMemo(() => props.type, [props.type]);

  console.log("Type:" + currentType);

  const handleFilesChange = async (files: FileList) => {
    // Select only the first file in the list:
    const file = files[0];
    console.log("change file:" + currentType);

    if (file) {
      try {
        const dataUrl = await readAsDataURL(file);

        // Set the selected file and its preview:
        setSelectedFile({
          name: file.name,
          data: dataUrl,
        });
        setFilePreview(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        setOpenDialog(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const openFileDialog = () => {
    console.log("open file dialog:" + currentType);

    const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput") as HTMLInputElement;
    fileInput.value = "";
    fileInput.click();
  };

  const handleDragOver = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  const handleDrop = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    const droppedFiles = event.dataTransfer.files as FileList;
    if (droppedFiles.length > 0) {
      handleFilesChange(droppedFiles);
    }
  };

  const profilePhoto = useAtomValue(profilePhotoAtom);
  const businessLogo = useAtomValue(businessLogoAtom);

  return (
    <Stack spacing="1rem">
      <Input
        id="fileInput"
        type="file"
        inputProps={{ accept: "image/png, image/jpeg", multiple: false }}
        onChange={async (e) => {
          const files = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files as FileList;
          await handleFilesChange(files);
        }}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <ElevatorDialog open={openDialog} onClose={() => setOpenDialog(false)}>
        <Stack sx={{ maxHeight: "44rem", maxWidth: "44rem" }}>
          <Cropper
            src={filePreview}
            onChange={onChange}
            stencilProps={{
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            }}
            stencilComponent={CircleStencil}
          />
          <Stack alignItems="center" sx={{ mt: "1rem", mb: "-1rem" }}>
            <DialogActionButton
              type="submit"
              loading={false}
              onClick={() => {
                console.log("currentType in onClick:", currentType);
                props.onSubmit?.(selectedFile, currentType);
                setOpenDialog(false);
              }}
            >
              <Typography
                fontFamily="Helvetica Neue"
                fontWeight="bold"
                color="white"
              >
                Apply
              </Typography>
            </DialogActionButton>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </ElevatorDialog>

      <ElevatorDialog
        open={openPreviewImg}
        onClose={() => setOpenPreviewImg(false)}
      >
        {profilePhoto || businessLogo ? (
          <Box
            component="img"
            src={props.type === PhotoType.PROFILE ? profilePhoto : businessLogo}
            sx={{ width: "37rem" }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Typography>Nothing to see here</Typography>
        )}
      </ElevatorDialog>
      <Stack direction="row" alignItems="end" spacing="-2.5rem">
        <ProfilePicture
          onClick={() => setOpenPreviewImg(true)}
          size="9rem"
          fontSize="3rem"
          type={props.type}
        />
        <Box
          component="img"
          src={addPhotoIcon}
          sx={{
            width: "2.7rem",
            height: "2.7rem",
            pb: "0.3rem",
            cursor: "pointer",
          }}
          onClick={openFileDialog}
        />
      </Stack>
      <Stack alignItems="center">
        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}>
          {props.type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + props.type.slice(1)}
        </Typography>
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

A weird thing happens when I try to upload a logo - I click on the plus (that triggers the first ElevatorDialog to open (and `<Input/>`).
And the props.type changed from "logo" to "profile".
When I try swipe the `<UploadOnePhoto/>` places and upload a photo it changes to "logo". It looks like it re-render and assign the first component's type.
Something even more strange is that here:

```
<Typography sx={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}>
    {props.type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + props.type.slice(1)}
</Typography>
```

The values are always correct! "profile" and "logo" accordingly.

**Flow / console output (when trying to upload a *logo*)**

> Type:logo
> open file dialog:logo
> change file:profile
> Type:profile
> change:profile

I tried using `useRef`, `useEffect`, `useMemo` and even just place `props.type` in all places with `currentType` and still no solution works.
I'll be glad to get some help! :)

Comment: I would like to understand, why did you need to use hooks in the first place. What I would like to try though, is destructuring the props as such `const {type, onSubmit} = props`, because as far as the code implies, the `type` variable is read-only, and it is required upon initiating the `UploadOnePhoto` (React) component.

Comment: Hey, I didn't use hooks in the first please. My first code was calling `props.type` without saving it to an `useState` or something. 
As for your answer, destructing it didn't change anything unfortunately :(